# How to use QItemSelectionModel for QComboBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How to use QItemSelectionModel for QComboBox?

```
BaseModel *baseModel = new BaseModel(data, this);
QItemSelectionModel baseModelSelected(baseModel);
ui->tableView->setModel(baseModel);
ui->comboBox->setModel(baseModel);
ui->tableView->setSelectionModel(baseModelSelected);
ui->comboBox->setSelectionModel(baseModelSelected); // can't
```

Comment: Why do you want to set a selection model on a combo box? Do you want to change the current value by selecting it from a list view?

Comment: I want to change the current value of comboBox by selecting it from a tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QComboBox` doesn't allow you to share a selection model. But, you can use the selection model of your view the update the combo box when the user selects a new item in the list.

For example:

```
QStringListModel* model = new QStringListModel(QStringList() << "Op1" << "Opt2" << "Opt3" << "Opt4");

QListView* view = new QListView();
view->setModel(model);

QComboBox* combobox = new QComboBox();
combobox->setMinimumWidth(200);
combobox->setModel(model);

QWidget* w = new QWidget();
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(w);
layout->addWidget(view);
layout->addWidget(combobox);

QObject::connect(view->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged, [=](
                 QItemSelection const& newSelection, QItemSelection const& previousSelection) {
    if (newSelection.isEmpty())
        return; // No selected item in the view. Do nothing

    // First selected item
    QString const item = newSelection.indexes().first().data().toString();
    combobox->setCurrentText(item);
});
```